# Windows Defender does not run an Offline scan. Event Viewer reports Event Id 5007

Tags: virus, anti-virus, windows-10, virus-removal

When I start the **Offline** scan from the **Windows Defender App** in Windows 10, as expected, it restarts my system and then only briefly attempts to run **Windows Defender Offline** but quickly restarts my system again in only 2 - 3 seconds or so instead of the 15 minutes or so it reports that it usually takes.

Why would that be?

I can't even tell if the thing actually ran.

I checked the Event Viewer and it reports two **Information** messages only and no errors.

```
Event Id: 2030
Windows Defender Antivirus downloaded and configured Windows Defender 
Offline to run on the next reboot.

Event Id: 5007
Windows Defender Antivirus Configuration has changed. If this is an 
unexpected event you should review the settings as this may be the result 
of malware.
    Old value: Default\IsServiceRunning = 0x0
    New value: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Defender\IsServiceRunning = 0x1
```

[From what I read](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/troubleshoot-windows-defender-antivirus), event Id `1000` means that the offline scan started, and event Id `1001` means that it completed. If these event Ids are not in the event log, then it means that the Windows Defender Offline process did not run.

I also checked the log files in the **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Defender\Scans\History\Service** folder but they are not helpful in indicating what actually happened, and esp. whether or not the process ran.

I am running Windows 10, version 1903, build 18362.476.

I ask this because I am a bit worried about a pen drive I [recently inserted into the USB interface of my computer](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/222479/68270) to copy some songs from. Windows Defender reported it was infected, so I immediately removed the pen drive and returned it to its owner without opening any of its files.

Both, a **Quick Scan** and a **Full Scan** report **0 threats found** but the **Protection History** shows 3 **Severe** entries, two of which were **Quanrantined** and removed. One has the status of **Abandoned** with the header **Remediation Incomplete**. Please see the picture below.

[image]

**So, in summation, my questions are:**

1. It appears that the Windows Defender Offline process did not run at all. Given the information, would you know why that is?
2. Other than the unhelpful message provided in the event log [and the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-antivirus/troubleshoot-windows-defender-antivirus), what actually does the Windows Defender Event Id 5007 mean? Do I have something to worry?
3. There is also no explanation of the **Abandoned** status in the documentation. Could you please elaborate on what that means and whether or not I should be worried?

Comment: @Overmind Blimey! I missed that. I have edited the text to make my questions more prominent. :-)

Comment: Your particular 5007 entry means the malware is killing the Defender process, make a boot drive from one of the 3rd party AV vendors and see if it can remove it, otherwise do a clean reinstall of the OS.>>>>>>https://www.techradar.com/best/best-antivirus-rescue-disk

Comment: @Moab Could you please point me to any record -- whether anecdotal or authoritative documentation -- that suggests that 5007, as in the case I highlighted above, is actually because of a malware?

Comment: I have this problem and it persisted after a Windows system reset. Other than a particularly crafty boot sector virus, I can't imagine how that could be the case. @sathyaish were you ever able to find a resolution on your own?